# Xpath in Safari Web Inspector not working

Tags: xml, xpath, safari, safari-web-inspector

I am trying to use xpath in the Safari Web inspector

I am using this local XML:

```
<searchable_index>
    <item>John</item>
    <item>Paul</item>
    <item>George</item>
    <item>Ringo</item>
</searchable_index>
```

I save it as a local file, I open Chrome and do:

$x('//item')

And it works without problems, returning this:

[image]

But when I try to do the same in Safari, it returns an empty array

[image]

Any clues why is this happening? Its driving us crazy

Im using Safari 8.0.3 (10600.3.18) in a Yosemite

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Are you sure you opened the same XML document?

Comment: Yes, we had tested two people with two diferent computers. We saved the file as *.xml, and opened with the browsers

Comment: Very strange indeed. Working fine with Safari 7.1.2 and Mavericks. Did you install the latest WebKit?

Comment: I think yes, my version of user agent is:  User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.18

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, if Safari 8 is selected as the user agent in the WebKit, and if the input file has a `*.xml` extension, then an XPath expression typed in the console will *not* search the source document, but the HTML generated on top of it, saying

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

and there are no `item` elements in that HTML document. Theoretically, you could change the view from "DOM Tree" to "Source Code", but that does not work if the user agent is Safari 8. Also, with a user agent that does allow switching to Source Code, the path expression still doesn't work.

Yet, changing the file extension to `*.html` will work. Then, try again and the Xpath expression will find the `item` elements.

If you cannot change the file extension, I think there is no way in Safari Web Inspector to find those elements. Then, you'd have to rely on another tool that evaluates XPath expressions against XML, whatever is available in your programming language or framework.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm doing the same and it works, but the problem is that I have to do the xpath to an external XML, from an iPhone/iPad webkit, and i can't change the extension.

Comment: And changing the user agent doesn't fix anything, it keeps failing

Comment: @Del Yes, I already deleted that part. See my edit, I don't think there is a way in this case.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much Mathias for your effort. Sorry to hear that